# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: flutter, dart

I just Installed Everything for flutter...and run the first default app...but this problem is showing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').

> File 'A:\yo\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Flutter Doctor-----

PS C:\Users\OPYKI> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.1.0-12.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.1)

[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: Can you check if you have Android SDK Build Tools installed? Try `flutter clean` to see if it helps

Comment: yes its installed...